# Lightbox not loading with RoyalSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox2

I am using RoyalSlider and Lightbox.js for this project. For some reason, it's not working - you can click on an image and it will pop up in the lightbox, but the image does not load.

A working demo of the site is http://bobbyomari.com/clients/opa -- just scroll to the bottom of the page and there is a horizontal slider. As you can see when you click on an image it doesn't the image.

HTML:

```
<section id="homeGallery" class="hidden-xs">
    <div id="homeGallerySlider" class="rsDefault">
        <div class="image-set">
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-1.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-2.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-3.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-4.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-set">
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-5.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-6.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-7.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#" data-lightbox="gallery"><span class="imgHover"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></span><img src="img/opa-home-gallery-1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Home Page Gallery Slider
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#homeGallerySlider').royalSlider({
        keyboardNavEnabled: false,
        autoScaleSlider: false,
        imageAlignCenter: false,
        imageScalePadding: 0,
        arrowsNav: true,
        arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
        randomizeSlides: false,
        slidesOrientation: 'horizontal',
        usePreloader: false,
        navigateByClick: false,
        slidesSpacing: 0,
        controlNavigation: 'none',
        imageScaleMode: 'none',
        loop: true,
        slideDrag: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
var slider = $('--element--').data('royalSlider');
    slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function (event, originalEvent) {
    //console.log(this);
    $.fancybox( this.currSlide.bigImage );
});
```

and replace --element-- with your slider. For example #homeGallerySlider

Cheers,
Ciprian